# Проверка выбранной в input даты

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть инпуты с выбором даты через `datepicker`. Как сделать проверку, если разница между СЕЙЧАС и выбранной датой больше N кол-ва месяцев - выводился бы алерт с ошибкой? Как я понял, нужно перевести дату которая выбирается `datepicker`'ом и сегодняшнюю в миллисекунды, их минусануть ?

Можно, пожалуйста, примерное решение? Спасибо.

Comment: @roman_r, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем есть такая функция, как [Date.parse()](http://javascript.ru/Date.parse)

Получаете время, введенное в инпуте, получаете текущее время (`new Date()`).
Сравниваете:

```
if((new Date()).getTime() - Date.parse('24/04/1012') > 1000*60*60*24) { // 1 день
   //...
}
```